# SQLite Error (' undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'') in C

Tags: c, database, sqlite

I want to connect a SQLite Database to a C program, but I always get this error. Maybe someone can help me.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sqlite3.h"

int main()
{
    sqlite3 *db;
    int rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
    if (rc != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed!");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Success!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you add the library to your linker section?

Comment: @Devolus I trued, but it still doesnt work.

Comment: How did you do this?

Comment: @Devolus I just found out that I didn't do the right thing. Can you please explain me how I can add it?

Comment: I don't know your environment or toolchain. How to add a library depends on your compiler setup.

Comment: I know it has been a while since I asked, but I wanted to thank you again @Devolus , because it works, now and your advise helped.

Comment: No problem... :)